# How to check the file size inside my C# program?

Tags: c#

How do I check inside my C# program that if the size of my program is not greater than 100mb for example, to not run or to auto-destroy itself when someone run it again ?

I tried to search everywhere, but I can't seem to find anything relatable.

Comment: @Satpal , Sorry, but I already checked that question and it doesn't have what I look for.
I want the code to get the file size from my program, without having a path.

Comment: please share relevant code

Answer (score 0):

```
// Get the information about a file
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(file);
// Print the file size to console
Console.WriteLine($"File size: {fi.Length} bytes");
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the current executable file name, then use the `FileInfo` class and it's Property `Length`, that [returns the file size in bytes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo.length?view=net-6.0):

```
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName);
//fi.Length <= 104857600 // that is 1024*1024*100 bytes
```